Reference for k-invertible cells in an n-category being (k+1)-invertible
A while ago, I read that if a cell in a strict n-category is invertible with respect to composition along its k-boundary, it is also invertible with respect to composition along its (k+1)-boundary. For instance, consider a 2-cell $\alpha : f \Rightarrow g : x \to y$ in an n-category, with a horizontal inverse $\alpha' : f' \Rightarrow g' : y \to x$, in the sense that $\alpha *_0\alpha' =id_{id_x}$ and $\alpha' *_0 \alpha = id_{id_y}$. Then the cell
$$id_g *_0\ \alpha' *_0 id_f$$
is a vertical inverse to $\alpha$.
In the paper I read the authors generalised this construction to k-invertible cells in a strict n-category for arbitrary k. However, I can't track down what this reference was. Can anyone help?

The source is Corollary 14.5.3 of Polygraphs: From Rewriting to Higher Categories!
